# How to use stereo camera for localization?

Tags: localization, navigation, stereo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a stereo camera and a sonar sensor, so I want to use this two sensors for localization, but I don't no use what software.Can you give me an idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64334/how-to-use-stereo-camera-for-localization?/) by [Keith](https://answers.ros.org/users/5058/keith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try getting pointcloud from stereo data.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc

You can use this 3D pointcloud to run SLAM algorithms VSLAM or maybe RGB-D SLAM.

Hope this helps..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Keith](https://answers.ros.org/users/5058/keith/) on 2013-06-17**:
Thanks! Iwill try.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use the images of the stereo camera to perform visual odometry. For example, [viso2_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros) is a ros package that takes stereo image as input and give you the pose of the vehicle.

You can integrate both, visual odometry and sonar into a Kalman Filter, but I don't know any package to do this. [Robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf) integrates visual odometry and imu.

Hope this helps...

---

Originally posted by [Pep Lluis Negre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4205/pep-lluis-negre/) with karma: 111 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Keith](https://answers.ros.org/users/5058/keith/) on 2013-06-17**:
Thanks! I will try.

**Comment by [Pep Lluis Negre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4205/pep-lluis-negre/) on 2014-09-16**:
You can also use the [stereo_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_slam) package to perform localization using only the stereo images. This package also includes the possibility to reconstruct the world using the pointclouds from the camera. See the videos in the link above ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) package to convert point cloud data to laser data, and then use [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl?distro=indigo) package for localizing the robot

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-09-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1